# What is headless_lib.pak? is it should copy to headless library to AArch64 devices?

Tags: ubuntu, chromium, headless

I built chromium headless shell for AArch64 on x64 Linux(Ubuntu) on Virtualbox.
I referred following page.

https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md

I want to install headless chromium c++ library in Ubuntu 19.10 on Raspberry Pi 4 to run.

What files should I copy to run it?

Is headless_lib.pak compressed file which contain entire files of chromium headless library?